# node.js - page keeps loading - no errors to investigate

Tags: node.js

this is `1.js` 
let's run it

```
node 1.js
```

and then on the web
execute:  `domain.tld/-2`

it all works perfect. 
i see it loaded `2.js` and then
used a function to do the mysql query
and displays all the results. perfect.

now on the web let's try to
go to : `domain.tld/-3`

`1.js` tries to load `3.js`
because the urlpath name is '/-3'
but there is no '`3.js`'

i am expecting it to say

```
"page not found'
```

`node 1.js` is not crashing.
and web browser is still.. '`loading..`"

here is the 1.js :

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcached = new Memcached('localhost:11211');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '--------------',
    user     : '2',
    password : '-------------',
    database : '1'
});

connection.connect();


var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
var pathname=url.parse(req.url).pathname;

if (pathname.match(/\/-\d{1,2}/)) {
     pathname = pathname.replace('-', '')

    try{
    var o = require('/' + pathname + '.js')
    } catch (err){
    var o = '0'
    }

    if (o == '0'){
        o = 'page not found'
    }else{
         o.makeQuery(connection, function(err, result){
             if(err) return res.end(err);
         o = result;
             res.end(o)
         });
    }

} else if (pathname.match(/^\/$/)) {
    res.end('welcome to index page');
} else {
    pathname = pathname.replace('/', 'o');
    res.end('welcome to user profile page');
}

}).listen(80);
```

although it may not matter.. 
here is the `2.js`

```
exports.makeQuery = function(connection, callback) {

  var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM 1_accounts order by ac_nu asc limit 5';

  connection.query(queryString, function(err,res,fields){
    if (err) {return callback(err)};

    bb = JSON.stringify(res);
    callback(null, bb);
  });
}
```

before i added the following segment to
1.js it was working fine via web.

```
if (pathname.match(/\/-\d{1,2}/)) {
} else if (pathname.match(/^\/$/)) {
} else {
}
```

in other words it must have something to do
with those perhaps.

before i added those lines..
it would smoothly display:

```
"page not found"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set o='page not found' but there is no response.write(o) or res.end(o) for it as it is in the else part hence it will never be displayed

Comment: this answer was correct.  perhaps someday i will figure a way to get out of these things in node.js called "asynchronous functions".. so that i can have only one res.end() at the end of everything. my mind was fixated on such style..that.. i kind of forgot about res.end() not being present there as well.

Comment: You can still do it by assigning o="xxxxxx" everywhere and putting res.end(o) just before }).listen(80); Also upvote the answer